# fetching more data with load more button without losing previous data redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, pagination, infinite-scroll

I want to only load 10 posts at a time, when i press the load more button I want to get 10 more posts on top of the previous 10. As of right now i get my first 10, when i press load more, i lose my first 10 and get the second 10. I'm using redux so its a bit confusing to me. I've read somewhere here to use `concat` in my reducers but it still dont work. Maybe my syntax is wrong? that post was from 2017.

```
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts(page));
  }, [dispatch, page]);

  return (
    <Container className="mt-4" style={{ maxWidth: "600px" }}>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <Col key={post._id} className="m-2 p-2">
              <Post post={post} />
            </Col>
          ))}
          <Button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>Load More</Button>
        </>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

My Reducer

```
export const postsReducer = (state = { posts: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, posts: [] };
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        posts: state.posts.concat(action.payload),
      };
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
```

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that in your `getPosts` action, It seems you are dispatching `PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_REQUEST` which initially sets post to an empty array. You might want to change that to just `return { loading: true }` without setting post to `[]`. So your reducer looks like this

```
export const postsReducer = (state = { posts: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        posts: [...state.posts, ...action.payload],
      };
    case PC.FETCH_ALL_POSTS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
```

Also, you may need to confirm that the redux store is not cleared on new post fetch probably d

Comment: How did you know when i didnt even show my actions? Your a legend. Thanks a bunch!